# LookupAddr causing nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: go, dns

I have the following code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    checkRdns("182.1.126.151")
}

func checkRdns(addr string) {
    names, err := net.LookupAddr(addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in getting rdns for", addr)
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(names)
}
```

This throws the error

```
Error in getting rdns for 182.1.126.151
lookup 182.1.126.151: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[]
```

Does this error mean that there is no Reverse DNS for this IP? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: Please confirm the lookup. You can use this https://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx

Comment: That IP address has no PTR record indeed (do `dig -x` to see), as you can't expect any IP address to have them, it is not required at all. Your code has probably nothing wrong hence.